# Having two objects move in an SwingBot

Tags: java, swing, timer, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make it so that both shapes move when the commands are pressed. My question is: How do I get the blue polygon to move along with the yellow rectangle? I can't seem to figure it out, no matter what I do. Any help is appreciated! thanks!

**EDIT:** Removed Timer Code (it is for something different)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Original {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        // contruction of new JFrame object
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();    
        // mutators
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setTitle("SwingBot");    
        // program ends when window closes
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        Robot r = new Robot();
        frame.add(r);
        // voila!
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // your Scanner-based command loop goes here        
        int noend = 0;
        System.out.println("Type a Command:");
        while(noend == 0)
        {
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             String command = input.next(); 
             if(command.equals("left"))
                 r.moveBot(-10,0);

             if(command.equals("right"))
                 r.moveBot(10,0);

             if(command.equals("down"))
                 r.moveBot(0,10);

             if(command.equals("up"))
                 r.moveBot(0,-10);
        }            
        // call methods on the Robot instance like w.moveBot(10,10) in response to
        // user input
    }    

    public static class Robot extends JComponent
    {
        private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20,60);
        private Polygon poly = new Polygon();

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;               
            // set the color
            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);                
            // draw the shape`
            g2.fill(rect);                
            int xPoly[] = {75, 125, 170, 170, 200, 105, 60};
            int yPoly[] = {75, 50, 88, 111, 125, 180, 150};    
            poly = new Polygon(xPoly, yPoly, xPoly.length); 
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawPolygon(poly);                
        }

        public void moveBot(int x, int y)
        {
            // move the rectangle 
            rect.translate(x,y);
            poly.translate(x,y);
            // redraw the window
            repaint();
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ignore the Timer Code, that's for something I haven't finished yet.

Comment: You might like to call `super.paintComponent` a little ealier, like before you actually paint anything.  And you really shouldn't be mixing console input with GUIs.  Take a look at [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I moved it, but it didn't change anything. Do you know if its possible to increase the thickness of your lines? btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Don't create the shapes in the `paintComponent` method.
- When creating them give them variables that can be changed
- In the `Timer` or key press, or where ever you are trying to move them, change those variable and call `repaint()`
- For multiple objects you can have a an `interface` like `Shape` where each `Shape` has a `move()` method that can be called.
- Loop through an data structure of those objects and call their `move()` methods, then repaint()`
- A `Shape` can have a `drawShape(Graphics g)` method, and you can loop through the data structure of `Shape` inside the `paintComponent` method and call `drawShape(g)`

You can see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871022/2587435) for an example.

[image]

---

### UPDATE

Here's an example of all the points I mention above.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MoveShape extends JPanel {

    List<Shape> shapes;

    public MoveShape() {
        shapes = createShapeList();

        InputMap im = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "moveRight");
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();
        am.put("moveRight", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (Shape sh : shapes) {
                    sh.moveRight();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private List<Shape> createShapeList() {
        List<Shape> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int xPoly[] = {75, 125, 170, 170, 200, 105, 60};
        int yPoly[] = {75, 50, 88, 111, 125, 180, 150};
        list.add(new MyPolygon(xPoly, yPoly, 6));
        list.add(new MyRectangle(75, 250, 150, 150));
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Shape sh : shapes) {
            sh.drawShape(g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(450, 450);
    }

    public class MyRectangle implements Shape {

        int x, y, width, height;

        public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        @Override
        public void drawShape(Graphics g) {
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void moveRight() {
            x += INCREMENT;
        }

    }

    public class MyPolygon implements Shape {

        int[] xPoints;
        int[] yPoints;
        int numPoints;

        public MyPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int numPoints) {
            this.xPoints = xPoints;
            this.yPoints = yPoints;
            this.numPoints = numPoints;
        }

        @Override
        public void drawShape(Graphics g) {
            g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, numPoints);
        }

        @Override
        public void moveRight() {
            for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.length; i++) {

                xPoints[i] += INCREMENT;

            }  
        }
    }

    public interface Shape {

        public static final int INCREMENT = 5;

        public void drawShape(Graphics g);

        public void moveRight();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Move Shapes");
                frame.add(new MoveShape());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @peeskillet has already pointed out...in your `paintComponent` method, you were re-creating the `poly` object each time it was called...meaning it never moved, and in fact was potential `NullPointerException` waiting to happen...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //...
    // This is a bad idea...        
    poly = new Polygon(xPoly, yPoly, xPoly.length);            
    //...
}
```

Instead, create the poloygon in the constructor to your `Robot` panel.

This example also demonstrates [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [Stroking and Filling Graphics Primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html)

[image]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Original {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setTitle("SwingBot");
                Robot r = new Robot();
                frame.add(r);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Robot extends JComponent {

        private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 60);
        private Polygon poly = new Polygon();

        public Robot() {

            int xPoly[] = {75, 125, 170, 170, 200, 105, 60};
            int yPoly[] = {75, 50, 88, 111, 125, 180, 150};

            poly = new Polygon(xPoly, yPoly, xPoly.length);

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "Up");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "Down");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "Left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "Right");

            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            am.put("Up", new MoveAction(0, -10));
            am.put("Down", new MoveAction(0, 10));
            am.put("Left", new MoveAction(-10, 0));
            am.put("Right", new MoveAction(10, 0));

        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            // set the color
            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

            // draw the shape`
            g2.fill(rect);

            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
            g2.drawPolygon(poly);
            g2.dispose();

        }

        public void moveBot(int x, int y) {
            // move the rectangle 
            rect.translate(x, y);
            poly.translate(x, y);
            // redraw the window
            repaint();
        }

        public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

            private int xDelta;
            private int yDelta;

            public MoveAction(int xDelta, int yDelta) {
                this.xDelta = xDelta;
                this.yDelta = yDelta;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                moveBot(xDelta, yDelta);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please, make sure you give all credit to @peeskillet, I just wanted to highlight some problem areas and solutions you might consider