# Java applet repaint a moving circle

Tags: java, applet, awt, graphics2d

I've just moved over from Pygame so Java 2D in an applet is a little new to me, especially when it comes to repainting the screen. In pygame you can simply do `display.fill([1,1,1])` but how do I do this in an applet in Java? I understand the use of `repaint()` but that doesn't clear the screen - any moving object is not 'removed' from the screen so you just get a long line of painted circles.

Here's my code that I've been testing with:

```
package circles;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;

public class circles extends Applet implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6945236773451552299L;
    static Random r = new Random();

    String msg = "Click to play!";
    static int w = 800, h = 800;

    int[] txtPos = { (w/2)-50,(h/2)-50 };
    int[] radiusRange = { 5,25 };
    int[] circles;
    static int[] posRange;

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int radius = 0;
    int cursorRadius = 10;

    boolean game = false;

    public static int[] pos() {
        int side = r.nextInt(5-1)+1;
        switch(side) {
            case 1:
                posRange = new int[]{ 1,r.nextInt(w),r.nextInt((h+40)-h)+h,r.nextInt(270-90)+90 };
                break;
            case 2:
                posRange = new int[]{ 2,r.nextInt((w+40)-w)+w,r.nextInt(h),r.nextInt(270-90)+90 };
                break;
            case 3:
                posRange = new int[]{ 3,r.nextInt(w),r.nextInt(40)-40,r.nextInt(180) };
                break;
            case 4:
                posRange = new int[]{ 4,r.nextInt(40)-40,r.nextInt(h),r.nextInt(180) };
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(side);
        return posRange;
    }
    public void start() {
        setSize(500,500);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {

    }
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics e) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) e;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis()%113==0) {
            x+=1;
            y+=1;
        }

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(x,y,20,20);

        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to call `super.paint(g);` in your `paint` method, as to not leave paint artifacts.
2. Never call `repaint()` from inside the `paint` method
3. Don't explicitly call `paint`, as you do in `update()`, when you mean to call `reapaint()`
4. just update the `x` and `y` values from inside the `update()` method, then call `repaint()`
5. You don't need to take a `Graphics` argument in `update()`
6. You need to call `update()` somewhere repeatedly in a loop, as it updates the `x` and `y` and `reapint()`s
7. If your class is going to be a `Runnable`, then you should put some code in the `run()` method. That's probably where you should have your loop

---

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class circles extends Applet implements Runnable {

    int x = 0, y = 0;

    public void start() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                update();
                Thread.sleep(50);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        x += 5;
        y += 6;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics e) {
        super.paint(e);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) e;
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);

    }
}
```

---

**Side Notes**

- Why use Applets in the first place. If you must, why use AWT `Applet` and not Swing `JApplet`? Time for an upgrade.

Here's how I'd *redo* the whole thing in Swing, using a Swing `Timer` instead of a loop and `Thread.sleep`, as you should be doing.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Circle extends JPanel{
    private static final int D_W = 500;
    private static final int D_H = 500;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    public Circle() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x += 5;
                y += 5;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new Circle());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

- See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- See [Create GUIs with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- Here's [more advanced example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871022/2587435) for you to look at and ponder.

---

**UPDATE**

> "Problem is, that's a JPANEL application. I specifically want to make an applet easily usable on a web page. "

You can still use it. Just use the JPanel. Take out the main method, and instead of Applet, use a JApplet and just add the JPanel to your applet. Easy as that.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CircleApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        add(new Circle());
    }

    public class Circle extends JPanel {

        private static final int D_W = 500;
        private static final int D_H = 500;

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        public Circle() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    x += 5;
                    y += 5;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `Applet vs JApplet` and all 1-7 items as well :)

Comment: I've mostly fixed everything, thanks for answering such a noobish question! Now my circle flashes/blinks constantly as it moves, how would I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Problem is, that's a JPANEL application. I specifically want to make an applet easily usable on a web page.

Comment: @HaydenPerry You can still use it. Just use the `JPanel`. Take out the `main` method, and instead of `Applet`, use a `JApplet` and just add the `JPanel` to your applet. Easy as that.

Comment: @HaydenPerry see my last **UPDATE**

Comment: *"I specifically want to make an applet easily usable on a web page."*  Then invent and build a time machine, and travel backwards in time at least 5 years.  In this day and age, no applet is 'easily usable'.  See [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for some of the history/detail behind my comment.