# Animations in Java not Working

Tags: java, swing, rendering

I am trying to animate a circle in Java. I want it to move every time I press a key, but it is not working. Is there a problem with the way I am drawing the circle? Am I forgetting a `repaint()` somewhere.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    int x = 300, y = 300;

    public Main() {
        super();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(x, y, 300, 300);
    }



    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        x++;
        y++;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(1200, 800);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.add(new Main());
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273376/java-applet-repaint-a-moving-circle

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `KeyListener`, honestly, make use of the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, which has been designed to resolve the issues which `KeyListener` creates.

`paintComponent` in `JPanel` does an important job, you are expected to call it's `super` method before doing any custom painting.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

You should also make an effort to initialise you UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this solves a number of known issues on some platforms, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You are not very far off.  First, you need to actually add a listener for your key events.

```
f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            m.keyPressed(e);            
        }

});
```

Second, you'll notice this uses 'm'.  That is a reference to your Main object.

Change:

```
f.add(new Main());
```

to:

```
Main m = new Main();

f.add(m);
```

Now it should work!