# Editing the height of a specific row in GridLayout Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, grid-layout

I want to edit the height of a single row in a JFrame with a GridLayout. Is there any way to do this or must the height of every row be constant?

Comment: `GridLayout` makes every component the same size, so all the rows will be the same height too. You have to use a different layout manager (`GridBagLayout` maybe, if you prefer to stay within the standard library).

Comment: You can nest panels, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22491318/230513).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this..

Not with a single `GridLayout`.

> ..or must the height of every row be constant?

Yes, every row in a single `GridLayout` is the same height, and every cell is the same width.

Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.